# Animating a shape in Python Plotly Dash without play button

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to create an animated gauge using Plotly and Dash. I have managed to do so with a simple pie plot with an added needle shape that rotates to a given value starting from zero.

[image: ![]()]

The problem I am facing is that I have added the animation of the needle using frames. These frames are currently linked to a Play button and the animation only works on clicking the button. **I would like to auto-play the animation as soon as the plot (page) loads - i.e. get rid of the play button completely.**

I found a few references that suggested dcc.Interval for the same but I am not able to figure out how do to this. Any help and suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks.

Here is my code for the animated gauge that works with a Play button.

```
import numpy as np

import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.offline as ofl
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.colors as pc

import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html


def createGaugePlot(gaugeValue=20):
    # Creating the Pie plot object using the labels and values
    pieTrace = go.Pie(
        name="Gauge",
        labels=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
        values=[20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        marker=dict(colors=["#0d0887", "#46039f", "#7201a8", "#9c179e", "#bd3786"], line=dict(color="rgba(0,0,0,0)")),
        hole=0.5,
        direction="clockwise",
        hoverinfo="none",
        textinfo="none",
        sort=False,
        showlegend=False,
    )

    shapeDefaults = dict(
        line_color="#888888",
        fillcolor="#888888",
        xsizemode="scaled",
        ysizemode="scaled",
        xref="x domain",
        yref="y domain",
    )
    needlePath = computeNeedlePath(gaugeValue=0)
    needleShape = dict(
        type="path",
        path=needlePath,
        line=dict(width=0),
    )
    circleShape = dict(
        type="circle",
        x0=0.47,
        y0=0.47,
        x1=0.53,
        y1=0.53,
    )
    layoutShapes = dict(
        shapes=[needleShape | shapeDefaults, circleShape | shapeDefaults]
    )

    animationFrames = []
    for v in range(gaugeValue):
        needlePath = computeNeedlePath(gaugeValue=v)
        animationFrames.append(
            go.Frame(
                layout=dict(
                    shapes=[dict(type="path", path=needlePath)],
                )
            )
        )

    frameSpeedOptions = dict(frame=dict(duration=10), transition=dict(duration=10))
    playButton = dict(
        updatemenus=[
            dict(
                type="buttons",
                buttons=[
                    dict(
                        label="Play",
                        method="animate",
                        args=[animationFrames, frameSpeedOptions],
                    )
                ],
                x=-0.2,
                y=1,
                xanchor="left",
                yanchor="top",
            )
        ]
    )

    fig = go.Figure(
        data=[pieTrace],
        layout=layoutShapes | playButton,
        frames=animationFrames,
    )
    
    fig.update_layout(
        autosize=False,
        width=360,
        height=360,
    )
    
    return fig

def computeNeedlePath(
    gaugeValue: int,
    needleWidth: float = 0.06,
    needleHeight: float = 0.37,
    needleOriginX: float = 0.5,
    needleOriginY: float = 0.5,
    ) -> str:

    gaugeRatio = (2 * gaugeValue - 100) / (2 * 100)
    theta = np.radians(-360 * gaugeRatio)

    origin = dict(x=needleOriginX, y=needleOriginY)
    point1 = dict(x=origin["x"] - needleWidth / 2, y=origin["y"])
    point2 = dict(x=origin["x"] + needleWidth / 2, y=origin["y"])
    point3 = dict(x=origin["x"], y=origin["y"] + needleHeight)

    newPoint1 = rotatePoint(point1, origin, theta)
    newPoint2 = rotatePoint(point2, origin, theta)
    newPoint3 = rotatePoint(point3, origin, theta)

    needlePath = f"M{newPoint1['x']},{newPoint1['y']} L{newPoint2['x']},{newPoint2['y']} L{newPoint3['x']},{newPoint3['y']} Z"
    return needlePath

def rotatePoint(point: dict, origin: dict, theta: float) -> dict:
    return dict(
        x=round(
            np.cos(theta) * (point["x"] - origin["x"])
            - np.sin(theta) * (point["y"] - origin["y"])
            + origin["x"],
            6,
        ),
        y=round(
            np.sin(theta) * (point["x"] - origin["x"])
            + np.cos(theta) * (point["y"] - origin["y"])
            + origin["y"],
            6,
        ),
    )


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1(
            children="Gauge plot",
        ),
        html.P(
            children="Animated gauge plot with rotating needle",
        ),
        dcc.Graph(
            figure=createGaugePlot(gaugeValue=100),
            animate=True,
            animation_options=dict(frame=dict(redraw=True), transition=dict(duration=10)), 
            config=dict(displayModeBar=False),
        ),
    ]
)

app.run_server(debug=True)
```